# When using char my_string[] = "some string" syntax, does the string in constants memory segment is erased or copied to stack?

Tags: c, string, memory, stack

When using the syntax `char my_string[] = "some string"` my_string appears in stack like a regular array. I tried to print some of the constants memory segment to check whether "some string" is erased from it after been copied to stack or not. My try goes as follows:

```
    char *memory_access = "";
    char my_string[] = "my string";
    printf("address | char value\n");
    for(int i = -100 ; i < 100 ; i++){
        printf("%p | %c\n", memory_access+i , *(memory_access+i));
    }
```

Well I couldn't find "my string", so I suspect the answer is that after been copied to stack, "my string" chars are erased from the memory segment. However, I cannot know it for certain. Is it indeed the case?

Comment: C does not require `"my string"` to exist in the stack or any particular place.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica does it mean that the reason "my string" is copied to my stack is a compiler decision?

Comment: Yes, a compiler decision.  Possibility: `"my string"`  exists outside stack space and copied in to `my_string[]` as needed.  Also method used to find it is questionable.

Answer (score 0):

There are many implementation attributes to this yet OP is likely looking in the wrong place.

> I couldn't find "my string",

`char *memory_access = "";` assigned the address of a *string literal* to `memory_access`.  This address must be potentially available after a function finishes and is likely not in stack space.  Thus `memory_access+i` is not looking in the stack.

Suggest instead

```
// char *memory_access = "";
const char *memory_access = (const char *) my_string;
```

Comment: First, thanks for you answer. Maybe I am to blame since I wasn't clear enough. I know to "my string" is saved in stack. But I would like to know whether it is duplicated, means it appears in stack and in constant memory segment or just in stack?